# How to get the table change script for SQL Server using SSMS 2017?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, windows

I'm having frequent table changes in my database, I'm using SSMS 2017, is there any easy mechanism for generating scripts for the changes made to the table. Or Are there any tools for managing this kind of stuff.

I have tried generating the scripts for table changes in the SSMS itself in the designer section, but it will create separate files for each save click after the structure change. I think there is a better mechanism for this. Writing scripts for each structure change took lots of time.

Comment: Did you check database auditing?

Comment: Consider using [SSDT database projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt) with the database source code in a source control system. The VS IDE or sqlpackage.exe command-line tool can generate (and optionally execute) a deployment script to upgrade the target db.

Comment: @Learning_DBAdmin No how can we do that?

Comment: Please check this link --> https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-audit-feature-ddl-event-auditing-examples/